# can't open '/run/secrets/kubernetes.io:erviceacount/token': No such file or directory on InitContainer

Tags: kubernetes, service-accounts, k8s-serviceaccount

I have a initContainer and I dont have /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io:erviceacount/token to curl API k8s, I dont find how to add a service account on initcontainer

```
initContainers:
- command:
  - sh
  - -c
  - |
    TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)...
  image: registry:curl-jk:latest
  name: curl-jk
```

i use this image on docker hub : https://hub.docker.com/layers/gempesaw/curl-jq/latest/images/sha256-3d98a78fe35523a189802454ea5975d2cb3aaf1cf1ebb56937fe0a1391f51652
Any help please

I follow this documentation, but not works https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#bound-service-account-token-volume

```
  volumes:
  - name: kube-api-access
    projected:
    sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          path: token # must match the path the app expects
      - configMap:
          items:
            - key: ca.crt
              path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
            - fieldRef:
                apiVersion: v1
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
              path: namespace
    initContainers:
    - command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)...
      image: registry:curl-jk:latest
      name: curl-jk
      volumeMounts:
      - mounthPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        name: kube-api-access
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have missed it but it seems like there is a correction on the 'volumeMounts:' section. It was misspelled as'mounthPath' and It should be like this:

```
     -mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount 
      name:   kube-api-access
```